# How to view the DNS address assigned by DHCP?

Tags: dns, dhcp

How to view the DNS address assigned by DHCP?

ifconfig can not show it.

```
$ ifconfig -a
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 90:e6:ba:22:6a:f2  
          inet addr:192.168.1.111  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::92e6:baff:fe22:6af2/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:224856 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:220040 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:166848627 (166.8 MB)  TX bytes:20256333 (20.2 MB)
          Interrupt:46 Base address:0x4000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:5889 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:5889 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:468885 (468.8 KB)  TX bytes:468885 (468.8 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:26:5e:e8:4f:8e  
          BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

Comment: What is returned by: **ifconfig | grep 'inet addr:'** ?

Comment: @david6           inet addr:192.168.1.111  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0

Comment: This should help you `cat /var/lib/dhcp3/dhclient.leases | grep dhcp-server-identifier`

Comment: @devav2 $ cat /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient-529bed02-363e-4e97-bd5d-9f63f42f17f2-eth0.lease |grep dhcp-server-identifier
  option dhcp-server-identifier 192.168.1.1;
  option dhcp-server-identifier 192.168.1.1;
  option dhcp-server-identifier 192.168.1.1;
  option dhcp-server-identifier 192.168.1.1;
  option dhcp-server-identifier 192.168.1.1;

Comment: @devav2  192.168.1.1 is my router address.

Comment: @david6 192.168.1.111 is my computer address.

Comment: @david6 please see the output of the ifconfig

Comment: ***What are asking for?***  The DHCP service assigns an IP address from a pool (or range).  A DNS server returns IP addresses for a hostname, domain, or mailbox (MX-record).  Your **ifconfig** output looks normal ..

Comment: @david6 I want to get the DNS address used by current network connection.

Comment: IP address of DNS server(s)? See @Anwar's answer. *Hostname? Something else?*

Answer (score 56, accepted):

For at least Ubuntu 15.10 onward (possibly also earlier versions) run  in a terminal:

```
nmcli dev show eth0 | grep IP4
```

`eth0` is the most common iface, but it could be `eth1`, `eth2`, etc.

For older versions use `nmcli dev list iface eth0 | grep IP4`.

Comment: Awesome answer! Appreciate your sharing! I got it.

Comment: Glad it helped.  I found it when I wanted a way to get that info, then parse it to display on demand, as i had 3 different possible DNS servers (ISP, Google, and OpenDNS).

Comment: As of 15.04, the command is `nmcli dev show`

Comment: With `nmcli dev show eth0` (as on 15.04) it also works on Debian Buster. Thanks!

Comment: hey @SergiyKolodyazhnyy you should add an answer, your command is the best one!

Comment: @YandryPozo Posted an answer, as requested :)

Comment: this throws `argument list not understood`

Comment: will not work without network-manager.

Comment: @mestia - Well, considering nmcli is a command-line tool which is used for controlling NetworkManager, that makes sense.

Answer (score 19):

Now that Ubuntu (and Debian and almost all distros) use **[systemd](https://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/)** (check with `file /sbin/init`) maybe the more elegant way to get this info is with:

```
systemd-resolve --status
# Or 
resolvectl dns
```

- [freedesktop.org docs](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-resolved.service.html)
- [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd-resolved): Use `systemd-resolve --status` where it says `resolvectl` (**`systemd-resolve` is a symlink to `resolvectl`**).
- If you have problems with DNS subsystem I suggest removing `resolvconf` package. [May conflicts](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/resolvconf/+bug/1782275) with `systemd-resolve`.

Comment: The perfect answer for systems not running NetworkManager.
Ubuntu 18.04, Ubuntu 19.10

Comment: It works in Raspbian too

Comment: Doesn't work in Buster. I get `Failed to get global data: Unit dbus-org.freedesktop.resolve1.service not found.`

Comment: @Aenfa Debian is out of scope, but maybe [this](https://superuser.com/a/1427312/500826) helps

Answer (score 14):

```
$ nm-tool
```

will also list DNS Servers.

Comment: +1 because this has been tested working up to 14.04 release. For 15.04 and newer release, use `nmcli` as suggested by the other answer instead.

Answer (score 9):

To get the DNS address open terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and type:

```
cat /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.leases | grep dhcp-server-identifier
```

Comment: There is nothing in the /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.leases, it is empty.

Comment: $ file /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.leases
/var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.leases: empty

Comment: try /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.eth0.leases

Comment: That a [useless use of `cat`](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html). You probably mean `grep domain-name-servers /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.leases` (`domain-name`, no `dhcp-server`).

Answer (score 9):

here it is:

```
cat /etc/resolv.conf
```

but do not edit this file

Comment: In recent Ubuntu releases (post 2012 I think) it won't be useful, since it will contain `nameserver 127.0.1.1`, referring to localhost dnsmasq installation.  It's better to query NetworkManager as written by @anwar-shah and @marty-fried

Comment: As you mention, that file can be edited and thus are not necessarily the addresses assigned by DHCP. Now if you edit it yourself then, obviously, it's going to be different -- but what if you use a company VPN? Or something else influences the file? That's why I think it's not a good answer, even if simple and universal. It's a good first place to look, but not a true answer by itself.

Comment: In Ubuntu 22.04 the command `grep nameserver /etc/resolv.conf` outputs `nameserver 127.0.0.53` also if the DNS server are correctly set.

Answer (score 4):

As a GUI alternative to @MartyFried's answer, try this.

1. Click on the Network connectivity icon on the top panel.
2. Select *Wi-Fi Settings*
3. It should show you the DNS server address

   [image: screenshot]

Comment: My Ubuntu has no any GUI desktop.

Comment: @VictorS it shows the same information as the other answer. I checked it

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it is convenient for gnome or KDE users.

Answer (score 2):

My actual solution(est 2015, Ubuntu 14.04), is this:

1. Start the CLI
2. Type: `sudo apt-get install gnome-system-tools`
3. After install succeeded, type at the terminal: `network-admin`

If you somehow can't do this then try this, though it's not good enough for me, but it got my job done:

1. type `dig google.com`
2. near the end you can see something like this(est. 2015) ;; SERVER: and then an IP address(at least, on my machine) THAT is the actual DNS server resolving the domain for you. That server can change per hostname though.

Answer (score 2):

In Ubuntu 16.04, the info from dhcp is written in: `/var/lib/NetworkManager/dhclient-<interface>.conf`

Answer (score 2):

As I mentioned in the comments (which by popular request has become an answer now), one can use `nmcli dev show` as of Ubuntu 15.04. Add `grep` to the mix and you're set:

```
$ nmcli dev show | grep 'DNS'                                                                                                                                                                     
IP4.DNS[1]:                  208.67.222.222
IP4.DNS[2]:                  208.67.220.220
```

Answer (score 1):

The below worked for me on 20.04 LTS and 22.04 LTS:

```
resolvectl status
```

It will show the DHCP advertised and current DNS servers for each interface. Any manually configured DNS servers will also show up.
You can see the DNS domain too (which I was looking for when I have found this thread).

```
Global
       Protocols: -LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
resolv.conf mode: stub

Link 2 (enp0s31f6)
Current Scopes: none
     Protocols: -DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported

Link 3 (wlp4s0)
    Current Scopes: DNS
         Protocols: +DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
Current DNS Server: 192.168.0.67
       DNS Servers: 192.168.0.67 192.168.0.66
        DNS Domain: home

Link 4 (docker0)
Current Scopes: none
     Protocols: -DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
```

Answer (score 0):

If your computer run behind of Router/WiFi of your *Internet Provider*, you'll get a **Private IP Address** from DHCP of Router, something like 192.168.0.2 or 192.168.1.100.

To get the **Public IP Address** of DHCP of DNS from your *Internet Provider*, you need run the follow command line on terminal:

```
dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com
```